# Review audit discrepancy

Tags: bug, review-audits

I recently got a review audit in the Triage queue, and when I looked at the question info, it said it had 0 answers, but had an accepted answer, which couldn't have been true. Why did this happen?

[Link to audit for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/13250341)

Comment: I have "answers 1" when going to the link you posted. Do you still see 0 (and can you screenshot that)?

Comment: It had "answers 0" before it was revealed as an audit, although I forgot to screenshot it.

Comment: Is the bug that the audit shows inconsistent data?

Comment: Isn't this another one of their "tricks"? Similar to how they reduce the score to 0?

Comment: They take real questions and alter them to create audits.  This is one of the changes.